# Android StackOverflowError on RelativeLayout

Tags: android, stack-overflow, android-relativelayout

My app is sending me error reports (through [ACRA](http://acra.ch/)): I often get an error of stackoverflow... I don't know where it happens... here's one of the logs:

```
ANDROID_VERSION="2.3.5"

PHONE_MODEL="GT-S5830"

USER_APP_START_DATE="2014-10-23T12:50:55.000+02:00"

USER_CRASH_DATE="2014-10-23T12:51:04.000+02:00"

STACK_TRACE="java.lang.StackOverflowError
at android.widget.RelativeLayout$DependencyGraph.findRoots(RelativeLayout.java:1289)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout$DependencyGraph.getSortedViews(RelativeLayout.java:1250)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.sortChildren(RelativeLayout.java:281)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:303)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:581)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:365)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:982)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:581)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:365)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:566)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:381)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:566)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:381)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:581)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:365)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:762)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:531)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8313)
at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:845)
at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1866)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)"
```

Is there some suggestion on how to trouble-shoot or to fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: where's the layout file? it is possible that you are making circular reference on it.

Comment: Are you implementing some kind of root Layout as a glorified ListView? By that I mean one giant RelativeLayout/LinearLayout with a **lot** of views in it?

Comment: show the layout to see the problem.

Comment: The problem is that I have at lest 10 Activities (with every activity having different layouts) and all I get is this log that shows no information on where this error is happening...

Comment: how many of your activities/layouts have a DrawerLayout? this may help narrow down which to look at.

Comment: @invertigo none of them